# Adding response Header in WSDL on runtime

Tags: soap, wsdl, siebel

We are using Siebel CRM for an inbound integration and using session management based soap requests and response. The problem is that when we generate WSDL from Siebel it does not include session management related header neither in request nor in response. We are using .net application to call Siebel inbound web service. 
Now, our .net application is based on the classes generated after de-serialization of the Siebel generated WSDL and it is not including session response header. Session response header is being inserted by Siebel on run-time. Due to this our .net application could not get the session header. 
What solution can be for the above problem from .net or Siebel side ?

Comment: Did you try looking into the doc or web search? The first search result I got was https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/EAI2/EAI2_WebServices34.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Siebel generates this part in it's WSDL, the examples on Oracle and other blogs mention that the extra Headers need to be sent in the incoming SOAP to Siebel, but they are not present in the generated WSDL.

You will have to modify the WSDL after it is generated from Siebel, and then add the header section in it. Then your .NET side can parse out this section. Or you will have to handle the session side in the .NET app.config file